# How to cache response in AFHTTPRequestOperationMnager

Tags: ios

This is my code. I set cachePolicy = DontLoad, but it still get data from server not from local cache. Why?

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    manager.requestSerializer = [AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer];
    manager.requestSerializer.cachePolicy = NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataDontLoad;

    AFHTTPResponseSerializer *responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
    responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"text/html"];
    manager.responseSerializer = responseSerializer;
    [manager GET:@"http://www.github.com" parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

        NSLog(@"%@", [[NSString alloc]initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

    }];
```

Comment: You can't test cache by random url, you need to setup cache control for your url, that might be your api.. http://php.net/manual/en/apc.configuration.php

Comment: like NSMutableURLRequest *request = //obtain request; 
request.cachePolicy = NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataDontLoad;

Comment: what is the difference if I use my url ? I think the policy CacheDataDonLoad won't consider it